# How to load Indexes to Teradata Server using BTEQ

Tags: database, indexing, syntax-error, database-migration, teradata

I'm trying to load table that has unique index to Teradata Server using BTEQ utility.
And I get the following error:
Failure 3706 Syntax Error: expecting something between the word 'ID' and the 'ASC' keyword.
It seems like BTEQ doesn't accept 'ASC' and 'DESC' keywords. However the syntax is valid, and if I run this in Teradata Studio it works, index is created.

CREATE
UNIQUE  INDEX IDX_UNIQUE_TEST_INDEX

(ID ASC) ON 
TEST_INDEX;

Could anyone please help me to find a solution. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is that the statement in the BTEQ script that is generating the error? If not can you post the BTEQ script?

Comment: Rob, I run bteq script from test_index.bat file that looks like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\Client\13.10\bin\bteq.exe" < test_index_ddl.bteq;

Comment: test_index_ddl.bteq looks like                              
.logon server_name/dbc, dbc;
DATABASE twm_results;
.run FILE=test_index_ddl.sql;
.run FILE=test_index_idx.sql;
.logoff;    

and finally, test_index_idx.sql looks like                       
CREATE INDEX IDX_TEST_INDEX     
(NAME ASC,
AGE ASC) ON 
TEST_INDEX;

CREATE UNIQUE  INDEX IDX_UNIQUE_TEST_INDEX     
(ID ASC) ON 
TEST_INDEX;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's no ASC or DESC in any Teradata index Teradata Studio probably removes it before running the query :-)

You might check DBQL what's actually submitted.

Comment: Dnoeth, thank you very much for your answer. Right, Teradata doesn't support ASC/DESC keywords in CREATE INDEX statement according to documentation. And in Teradata Studio 14.0 it doesn't seem to work.